# How can I use different subdirectories as my root based on a cookie/URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm setting up a website that will go through changes periodically, and the owner of the site would like to be able to provide a link to certain people that would show them the new layout. So far, we are able to point the main URL to a subdirectory for those files, but we'd like to be able to change the subdirectory based on a certain URL, or a cookie on their machine.

For example, when someone visits example.com, it uses the directory ws_2013 to display the site. All of the files are in that subdirectory, but example.com never uses that directory in the URL. Now, the owner of the site wants to show someone the new layout they're working on via URL, and sends them to example.com/2014/, but he wants that URL to pull files from the ws_2014 subdirectory, but without using ws_2014 in the URL.

Here is what we have in our htaccess file right now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ws_2013/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ws_2013/$1  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ws_2013/ [L]
```

We tried adding a line at the top like this for cookies:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*view=2014 [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws_2014/ [L,R=301]
```

But, that didn't work. I'm not that great with htaccess, and I'm not sure how to go about this. Could anyone provide with me some information on how I can go about this, or if it's possible? Basically, the URL's would be as follows, but would pull from a different subdirectory without the need to rewrite URL's.

example.com/ -> ws_2013

example.com/2014/ -> ws_2014

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: You could build some elaborate thing... But can't you just define another virtual host with a slightly other domain name (`2014.whateverthedomain.is`? That would be infinitely easier.

Comment: @Wrikken I didn't really think of that. I can't believe that didn't cross my mind. Do you think the current redirect we have is okay? It seems busy, but that's what I was able to find online.

Comment: As you don't need to rewrite it with just a couple of vhosts, I would just make that 2013 directory the document root. It seems OK at a glance, but if you can avoid it, we avoid all less obvious / obscure bugs, and we needn't bother with it at all. If you've got shared resources/assets like images, I'd just symlink them in the different roots. Bonus points: if you use a [`VirtualDocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot), you don't even need to touch apaches config for new trials. You can't rely on `DOCUMENT_ROOT` anymore at that point though.